# Running Starcraft 2 from different computers

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

If you install your Starcraft 2 on five different computers, will Blizzard complain? (I'm sure there *is* a limit, e.g. if you install on 1000 computers you will get banned).

What happens if you try to run the game simultaneously from different computers? (Will it just not work, or will you get harassed by Blizzard?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not as long as you use a Battle.Net account you associated with the game

Also, Battle.Net prevents you from logging in from multiple locations with the same account, so you can't even create an unwanted situation

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SC2, but if you do that with WoW (which uses the same battle.net system for authentication), Blizzard will sometimes change the password for you (saying they detected a hacking attempt on your account) and email you the new password.

So if you find you can't log in for some reason don't panic and check your email (the junk/spam folders too)!